# How likely is it to get a phone call on Didi ("Uber in China")?

Tags: china, taxis, language-barrier, chinese-language

I travel for China now but it is sometimes hard to get a taxi here (I'm in Chongqing) since the driver can deny the route he doesn't like. So I would rather try Didi, a clone of Uber in China (I have never used Uber in any other countries, though).

However, when I hangged out with my friend and she tried to use it to go back to home, she got a phone call by the driver after booking. The driver instructed her to walk to the car as the car can't go back on the road.

My oral Mandarin Chinese is pretty bad and it is near impossible to get decent talks via a phone, let alone Chongqinese language. I understand written Mandarin Chinese, though.

So how likely is it to get a call by a driver, or be forced to call to a driver in Didi? If it is too frequent I would not like to use it...

Comment: Why not give it a try? I've seen Uber drivers who text "I am deaf" to passengers, implying that one shouldn't call them. Maybe you could do the same - text "I am deaf" in Chinese right after calling a cab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very likely, and you often will not even find the car unless you call the driver, or they call you. I can't speak for Chongqing as I haven't been there in quite a while, but in Shenzhen and Beijing this is how Didi works; I doubt Chongqing would be any better, if not worse.

However, you could try and just explain to them in written Mandarin (i.e. texting) that you are a foreigner and would prefer texting. They'd usually be understanding.